# Unable to install oracle adf mobile extension in jdeveloper

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile

I have tried all means to install adf mobile extension but i keep getting this error:

```
Jul 9, 2013 4:09:24 PM org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents logged
INFO: Turning on modules:
Jul 9, 2013 4:09:24 PM org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents dumpModulesList
INFO:     org.openide.util.lookup [8.3.1 201007282301]
org.openide.util [8.6.2 201103231602]
org.openide.modules [7.17.2 201008301741]
org.openide.filesystems [7.38.2 201007282301]
org.netbeans.bootstrap/1 [2.33.5 201104201301]
org.netbeans.core.startup/1 [1.25.5 201103231602]
org.netbeans.libs.osgi [1.1.1 201007282301]
org.netbeans.core.netigso [1.4.5 201011191627]
oracle.ide_osgi [11.1.2 11.1.2
org.netbeans.core.dynamicconfig [1.0 130507]
org.apidesign.netbinox [1.16.10 110502]
com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbbridge [1.1 130507]
Jul 9, 2013 4:09:24 PM oracle.ideimpl.webupdate.WebUpdateAddin loadHookClass

SEVERE: Cannot load extension oracle.adf.mobile
```

Comment: Jdev Version and OS? also Java version?

Comment: Jdev - 11.1.2.4.0, OS - ubuntu 12.04, Java1.7.0_55